# Optional Changes to Model in NodeJS

Tags: database, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Nodejs with Sequelizejs but I suppose this question could apply to other situations.

An object comes in to my method with a some properties attempting to update the model I pull from the database (if I find a match).

```
var changes = {
   firstName: "foo",
   loginPin: 0000
}
```

The model contains many more properties but for the sake of this discussion here is an example.

```
var existingEmployeeModel = {
    firstName: "bar",
    middleInitial: "f",
    loginPin: 1111,
    email: "foo@bar.com"
}
```

So right now I basically look at processing it like this:

```
if (changes.firstName) existingEmployeeModel.firstName = changes.firstName;
```

Is there a better way to do this? Ocassionally I may `.trim()`, etc but I can't imagine this is ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, lodash `apply` http://lodash.com/docs#assign function does something similar. Just call it as follows:

```
_.assign(existingEmployeeModel, changes);
```

It should copy all the properties from the `changes` to the model.

If you do not want to add a dependency, you can use this one:

```
function apply(model, changes) {
  Object.keys(changes).forEach(function (key) {
    if ('string' === typeof changes[key]) {
      model[key] = changes[key].trim();
    } else {
      model[key] = changes[key];
    }
  });
}
```

Done.

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll be back with an 'answer' vote once I'm able to test this out.

Comment: My only question then would be if I have a property that is another object itself. I'd just do a typeof (property) === object and then another .keys()? Sounds simple enough